# canging jQuery cousing some custom widgets to stop functioning correctly or at all

Tags: javascript, jquery

just changed the jQuery from 1.8.2 to 1.11.3 only to discover that one of my own scripts stopped functioning correctly. More specifically only the `animate` is working and any other functions inside don't.

Also, what is little weird is that on page load on class names `out` and `close` element style is added `display:none;` I have no idea where it is set from, I assume jQuery does it automatically?

Here is my jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js?ver=1.11.3" async></script>
```

Here is my html:

```
<div id="slideout">
<a class="out"></a>
<a class="close out"></a>
<a data-pin-do="embedPin" href="http://www.pinterest.com/pin/[my pin id]/"></a>
</div>
```

here is my script:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(function(obj) {
            var slideout = $("#slideout");
            var out = $(".outer");
            var close = $(".closer");

            slideout.animate({
                right: "-200px"
            }, 1000, function() {

            });

            out.click(function () {
                if(!$(this).hasClass('in')){
                $(this).addClass("in");
                slideout.animate({
                    right: "0px"
                }, {
                    queue: false,
                    duration: 500
                });
                }
            });

            out.click(function() {
                $(this).removeClass("in");
                slideout.animate({
                    right: "-200px"
                }, {
                    queue: false,
                    duration: 500
                });
            });

            close.click(function() {
                $(this).removeClass("outer");
                slideout.animate({
                    right: "-200px"
                }, {
                    queue: false,
                    duration: 1000
                });
                slideout.fadeOut({
                    duration: 1000
                });
            });
        });
    }, 4000);
});
    (function (d) {
        var f = d.getElementsByTagName('SCRIPT')[0],
            p = d.createElement('SCRIPT');
        p.type = 'text/javascript';
        p.async = true;
        p.src = '//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js';
        f.parentNode.insertBefore(p, f);
    }(document));
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`toggle(fn,fn)`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) was deprecated in version 1.8 and removed in version 1.9.

You will need to refactor your use of it to a click event. Use `hasClass()` to check current state and react accordingly

Comment: Oh OK, how do I do this?

Comment: Change to a click event and use hasClass() to check it's state and a conditional based on that state

Comment: OK let me give it a try and I will post back in few minutes

Comment: I have changed it, but it still does not do what it supposed to do: here it is             <code>out.click(function () {
                $(this).addClass("in");
                slideout.animate({
                    right: "0px"
                }, {
                    queue: false,
                    duration: 500
                });
            });</code>

Comment: you aren't checking `if($(this).hasClass('in'))` and reacting according to that

Comment: I have tried this too             'code' out.click(function () {
                if(!$(this).hasClass('in')){
                $(this).addClass("in");
                slideout.animate({
                    right: "0px"
                }, {
                    queue: false,
                    duration: 500
                });
                }
            });

Comment: what is `out`? create a demo that reproduces this

Comment: no class `outer` shown in the html. Create a demo in jsfiddle

Comment: should be an `else` not 2 separate click handlers and you didn't include jQuery in demo ( see error in console). Is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/ud2bp9be/1/